# No rows rendered by embertable but colums show up

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-table

I am using the newest ember and embertable. Tried to use example from the page and rewrite it for use in my MVC project. Problem is that rows will not show but the columns show.

Is this a problem with the new ember version?

Edit: Putting som more information here.

HTML

```
            <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
          <div class='presentation-container'>
            {{view Ember.Table.TablesContainer controllerBinding="tableController"}}
          </div>
        </script>
```

The output(No rows =/ )

> Date Entry Low Open Volume High Close

EmployeetaskController

```
App.EmployeetasksController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    tableController: Ember.computed(function () {
        return Ember.get('App.EmployeetasksController.TableController').create();
    }).property() });

App.EmployeetasksController.LazyDataSource = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
    init: function () {
        console.log('EmployeetasksController.LazyDataSource init');
      enter code here  this._super();
    },
    objectAt: function (idx) {
        console.log("Lager rad");
        var date, row;
        row = this.get('content')[idx];
        if (row) {
            return row;
        }
        date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + idx);
        row = {
            index: idx,
            date: date,
            open: Math.random() * 100 - 50,
            high: Math.random() * 100 - 50,
            low: Math.random() * 100 - 50,
            close: Math.random() * 100 - 50,
            volume: Math.random() * 1000000
        };
        this.get('content')[idx] = row;
        return row;
    }, });

App.EmployeetasksController.TableController = Ember.Table.TableController.extend({
    init: function () {
        console.log('EmployeetasksController.TableController init');
        this._super();
    },
    hasHeader: true,
    hasFooter: true,
    numFixedColumns: 0,
    numRows: 500000,
    rowHeight: 30,
    columns: Ember.computed(function () {
        var columnNames, columns, dateColumn, entryColumn;
        columnNames = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'];
        entryColumn = Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create({
            columnWidth: 100,
            headerCellName: 'Entry',
            contentPath: 'index'
        });
        dateColumn = Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create({
            columnWidth: 150,
            headerCellName: 'Date',
            getCellContent: function (row) {
                return row['date'].toDateString();
            }
        });
        columns = columnNames.map(function (key, index) {
            var name;
            name = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
            return Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create({
                columnWidth: 100,
                headerCellName: name,
                getCellContent: function (row) {
                    return row[key].toFixed(2);
                }
            });
        });
        columns.unshift(dateColumn);
        columns.unshift(entryColumn);
        return columns;
    }).property(),
    content: Ember.computed(function () {
        console.log("Lager array");
        return App.EmployeetasksController.LazyDataSource.create({
            content: new Array(this.get('numRows'))
        });
    }).property('numRows') });
```

The view

```
App.EmployeetasksView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: 'ember-app',
    templateName: 'employeetasks'
});
```

Comment: Please show us your effort, possibly by creating a fiddle in jsfiddle.net . It is very hard for us to help you if you don't specify what your problem is. This does _not_ sound like a general problem with ember.js .

Comment: Did you include the css that came with the examples?

Comment: yes, and I have included jquery, jquery mousewheel and ui.

Answer (score 0):

Outdated ember and handlebars fixed it.